# how to create hash of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby

UPDATE: the answer is below by me a simple .merge is what was needed.

I need to get a hash of hashes as output from my build_virtual_boards_hash method
I can not figure out how to add the hash to a stack of hashes. Or even how to create such a thing...first I'll list the methods out and then show you the output I am getting.

Here are the two methods that are used...the problem is located inside 'build_virtual_boards_hash'...

```
def build_virtual_boards_hash(board, player)
  virtual_board = board.dup

  virtual_board_hash = {}
  new_board_hash = {}

  empty_spaces_on_board = virtual_board.grid.select{ |k, v| v == " " }.keys
  index_mark = 'VB'+empty_spaces_on_board.length.to_s

  #THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM IS
  #HOW DO I ADD EACH LOOP RESULT TO -SOMETHING- 
  #THAT CAN BE CALLED ON LATER AFTER THE LOOP ENDS
  #SO I GET THE DESIRED RESULTING OUTPUT?
  # 
  empty_spaces_on_board.each do |empty_space_symbol|
    # create a hash
    new_board_hash = {index_mark => move_as_somebody(board, player, empty_space_symbol).grid} #value
    p new_board_hash  
  end

end


#takes board....returns new board
def move_as_somebody(board, player, empty_space)
  new_board = board
  if player == 'X'
    new_board.grid[empty_space] = player
  else
    player == 'O'
    new_board.grid[empty_space] = player
  end
  return new_board
end
```

I currently get this output from these two methods...

```
{"VB7"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}}
{"VB7"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}}
{"VB7"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}}
{"VB7"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}}
{"VB7"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}}
{"VB7"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :c1=>"X", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "}}
{"VB7"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :c1=>"X", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"X"}}
```

What I need is this...

```
virtual_boards = {
    {"VB7"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}},
    {"VB6"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}},
    {"VB5"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}},
    {"VB4"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}},
    {"VB3"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}},
    {"VB2"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :c1=>"X", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "}},
    {"VB1"=>{:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :c1=>"X", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"X"}}
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: That's not a valid hash. Do you want an array?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: no, it's not a homework problem...I'm just a noob

Comment: added the move_as_somebody method which creates the first hash

Comment: I think the question is too "complicated" and too much tied to your problem. Try to provide a simpler abstraction.

Comment: sergio is saying its not a valid hash because, in your last code block, all your `Board` instances are one and the same since they share the same address `0x007f9ab388f018`, so theres no way `@grid` have all these different value.  <br/> I don't think that's you intended to communicate tho, the hash that you say you need looks like you copy and pasted it together.

Comment: Your `hash_o_hashes` is actually a hash of a hash of a hash… is that really what you want? The outer hash only has one key/value pair.

Comment: Also `=!` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the problem with hash of hashes is how to initialize deep hash.

This problem has been already solved and put to [Ruby Facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/rubyfaux/?doc=http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/docs/facets-2.9.3/core.json#api-class-Hash/api-method-Hash-d-autonew)

```
h = Hash.autonew
```

Now you can easy initialize the hashes in this manner:

```
h[:h1][:key] = 'value'
h[:h2][:key] = 'value'
...
```

Comment: Or eschew yet another library and initialize the Hash yourself:
`hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }`

Comment: @davidcelis so where EXACTLY do I place this? Are you saying that this  virtual_board_hash = {index_mark.to_sym => new_board_hash}... becomes this...virtual_board_hash= Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }

Comment: sorry kids...this is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

And the Answer is....

```
#builds hash of hash of fake boards
def build_virtual_boards_hash(board, player)
  virtual_board = board.dup
  i = 0
  virtual_board_hash = {}
  new_board_hash = {}

  empty_spaces_on_board = virtual_board.grid.select{ |k, v| v == " " }.keys


  while i < empty_spaces_on_board.length do
    p empty_space_symbol = empty_spaces_on_board[i]
    p index_mark = 'VB'+i.to_s

    new_board_hash = {index_mark => move_as_somebody(board, player, empty_space_symbol).grid}

    virtual_board_hash = virtual_board_hash.merge(new_board_hash)        

    i += 1
  end
  p virtual_board_hash
end
```